# Troubles with UIScrollView as Secondary View

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, interface-builder

I've been working on this for a few hours now, and I can't quite get the desired behavior out of my `UIScrollView` as a secondary view. I have a secondary view named `newDogView` that contains 3 stack views. I add `newDogView` and set up it's constraints in code.

My intent is to present `newDogView` (which is 960x320) as a smaller view (320x320) with the ability to scroll horizontally. The current outcome is that the view is added, but it stays 960x320. I think the confusion is either coming from the stack views or the fact that it's a secondary view, and not inside the view controller.

Here's the relevant code:

```
override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    newDogView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    newDogScrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    newDogScrollView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 320.0).isActive = true
    newDogScrollView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 960.0).isActive = true
    newDogScrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: 320, height: 320)
    newDogView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 320.0).isActive = true
    newDogView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 320.0).isActive = true
    newDogView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    newDogView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
}
```

I wasn't sure if I was supposed to set the height and width of newDogView.

Here is my current view hierarchy and warning:

[image: Here is my view hierarchy and warning.]

Here is my current storyboard:

[image: Here is my storyboard.]

I have constraints pinned to all sides on the `Content View` and the `Scroll View`.

Here's what the views currently look like on my iPhone:
[image: iphone photo]

Comment: If you set the height and width, then what is the behaviour?

Comment: You need to ensure that you have constraints to either implicitly or explicitly set the size of the scroll view and you need to set the scroll view's content size property so that the content can be sized correctly.

Comment: @Paulw11 please see my updated code and edits.

Comment: Why are you setting 920 here, shouldnt you be setting 320 ?newDogView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 960.0).isActive = true

Comment: @3stud1ant3 I updated the code and the screenshot. Still not the desired behavior. The view doesn't scroll.

Comment: Try change the content size from CGSize(width: 320, height: 320) to CGSize(width: 960, height: 320)

Comment: @3stud1ant3 Strangely, the view is now scrolling, but the stack views are somewhat misplaced. The first stack view is aligned, but the others are raised half way off the view. Also, the text fields are not responding to touch.

Comment: I think you need to set constraints on other views that are misplaced

Comment: @3stud1ant3 Please add an answer so I can select it. You've helped me through this problem.

Comment: What point exactly solved your problem?

Comment: @3stud1ant3 Changing the newDogView.widthAnchor to 960, and changing the contentSize to 960. Also I added more constraints to the newDogView's stack views to make the overall width and height more explicit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try change the content size from

```
CGSize(width: 320, height: 320)
```

to

```
CGSize(width: 960, height: 320)
```

and also change

```
newDogView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 960.0).isActive = true
```

to

```
newDogView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 320.0).isActive = true
```

Comment: It sure seems like UIScrollViews are fiddly to get right. It seems to me like the width of the view should be what you want the visible window to be. and the content size should be the total width/height of the stuff inside the scroll view. Neat! Thanks for your help.

Comment: @CodyPotter yes you have understood it right and you are always welcome, cheers